# Note on the entry stamp by US immigration

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, customs-and-immigration

I have entered the US using B2 visa. The interview was long and I told the officer I am staying for a few weeks and showed my return ticket.

When she stamped me in, I was admitted for 6 months but she wrote "Transit" under the date. I believe it happened because I got confused by the last question or she didn't understand me. Question was smth like "so you are in transit to your home country". I told her yes which for me meant that I am not planning to stay long term....

Does this "transit" have a great meaning? My I-94 confirms the 6 months admittance.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "I-94 confirms the 6 months admittance"

Comment: @Midavalo Thanks. So I shouldn't worry? I stated my intent at the very beginning and towards the end, I thought she was asking about my ticket again.

Answer (score 2):

The United States doesn't really have a 'transit' state. If you make it past immigration/customs, you're now in the country.

Even changing planes to fly to another country (e.g. Canada to Mexico via Atlanta) you'll likely go through customs/immigration and enter the US, legally.

So yes, you're admitted, for 6 months, as per the I-94.